# How do Eagles operate in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

Can an eagle companion to a ranger "flank" in order to give the beast master advantage on an attack?

Can eagles occupy spaces, just like regular creatures?

Do eagles have disadvantage on saving throws versus spells like *Gust of Wind*?

Comment: I think a bit more context would help here - the Eagle is your animal companion? And you're using the optional Flanking rules from the DMG?

Comment: @Carcer can you turn that into an actual answer please? As a comment it will get deleted

Comment: I meant it as an opportunity for the asker to clarify their question but sure, I'll optimistically answer.

Comment: If you think there are issues with the question that make it difficult/impossible to answer then don't, but equally don't leave a half-answer in comments as that's the worst thing you can do. Vote to close and wait for the questioner to clarify/edit the question so that it is answerable

Comment: Are you wondering these things simply because there is no description under the entry for "Eagle" in the MM? If so, you should indicate that is *why* you're confused on these details so that people can point you in the right direction.

Comment: The edit improved things but it's still asking too many different things.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, but I think the root of the things you are asking is this:

**Is a beastmaster's animal companion treated any differently in combat to a normal creature?**

The answer to that question is no - unless specifically otherwise stated by an ability, the animal companion is functionally a normal creature of that type. Animal companions get some bonuses and ability which make them a bit more effective in combat than a normal creature but don't fundamentally change the nature of how combat works.

So - the animal companion occupies a space in map-based combat the same way as any other creature of its size would do. If your DM is using the Flanking optional combat rule, an animal companion can help an ally (it doesn't have to be the beastmaster!) to flank an enemy.

There is nothing I can see in the description of Gust of Wind or the Eagle that would cause Eagles (or any other flying creature) to have disadvantage on saving throws against Gust of Wind.